# Is there a way to avoid content duplication on multi site setup?

Tags: multi-site, multi-domain

I have just crated a multi site according to the instructions on Crafts page.
Lets just say I have:

- siteone.com with template forlder templates/siteone
- sitetwo.com with template forlder templates/sittwo

It all works fine however all templates from templates/siteone can also be accessed on sitetwo by simply going to sitetwo.com/siteone/site-one-only-template

Is there a way to prevent that?

---

I've went through all the pages and added "_" to the template filename, then updated template paths of each single to reflect that. This now works as expected, however what's the point of site specific template folder if it's still routed to by other sites?

Answer (score 1):

That would probably be the Propagation Method setting in the channel´s settings. There you can choose "Only save entries to the site they were created in" (among other options). The thing is not your template path, but that the entry is stored to both sites (which is useful for, say, two sites that are just different language versions of the same site, and should have the same content).

Comment: Yes the channels are not an issue, the singles are

Comment: There’s the site settings on the single, isn’t it? With radio buttons for which sites it should be available in?

Comment: There is but, I can still get to the singles by using template name, which for me is usually the same as the page slug. Going through all singles and prefixing their template names with "_"  solved this, but I would still expect the routing to ignore templates from other site folders.

Comment: Ah, okay. Then I'm a bit at a loss, I totally agree that a single that isn't available for a certain site shouldn't be available (unless specifically fetched programmatically or similar)